# How to I use SUMIF or SUMIFS to automatically add the values of different cells when they meet they meet multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Basically I have a spreadsheet with three criteria columns.
I would like to be able to recognize duplicate HTS codes that also have the same country of origin and add the sum of those values, which then would add them to my separate column if those values are over $2500 added together.
I'm no Excel expert and I've tried utilizing SUMIF and SUMIFS but I can’t quite get it doing what I need it to do.

Any help would be appreciated. I apologize if this has been posted before; I haven’t been able to find it.

My spreadsheet looks like this

```
12   US        155
17   UK         87.66
39   US        183
42   US         87.8
58   CHINA       3.36
60   CHINA     504
64   US        794.28
64   US       3173.5
64   US      43685.4
64   US       1566.4
70   US         37.4
70   US       1159.4
83   US        443.06
95   CHINA       4.59
95   CHINA     108.56
95   CHINA     218
95   CHINA      53.2
95   MX        666.6
```

Comment: So, is the first column the “HTS code”? And you want to sum values from the third column? Please (1) try to explain more clearly, (2) show us a hand-computed example of the results you want, and (3) tell us what formulas you’ve tried.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommending using a Pivot table for this:

1. Add HTS and Country of Origin as Row Labels
2. Put your value as "Values".  If it's numeric, it will default to summing automatically
3. Set a "Value Filter" of "Greater than" 2500.

[image]